# compare keys in two dictionaries and update values with for loops

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, geojson

A GeoJson with point features contains two attributes: *City* and *Rating*. 
*City* as identifier is never changing, but *Rating* will be updated on a regular basis. 
The new *Rating* is stored in a dictionary as vales ("dnew"). 
My for loop is not working well. Please see the code below, where "#here is the problem" marks the problem which I cannot solve.

```
import json

dnew = {"Budapest": "fair", "New York": "very good", "Rome": "awesome"}

data = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "Cities",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name":     "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "City": "New York", "Rating": "good" },     "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.991836734693834,     40.736734693877537 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "City": "Rome", "Rating": "fair" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 12.494557823129199, 41.903401360544223 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "City": "Budapest", "Rating": "awesome" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 19.091836734693832, 47.494557823129256 ] } }
]
}

#at this point, keys of two dictionaies are compared. If they are the same, the value of the old dict is updated/replaced by the value of the new dict
for key in data["features"]:
    citykey = (key["properties"]["City"])
    ratingvalue = (key["properties"]["Rating"])
    #print(citykey + "| " + ratingvalue)

    for keynew in dnew:
        citynew = (keynew)
        ratingnew = dnew[keynew]
        #print(citynew + " | " + ratingnew)
        print(citykey + "==" + citynew)

        if citykey == citynew:
            #
            #here is the problem
            #
            data["features"]["properties"]["Rating"] = ratingnew
            print(True)
        else:
            print(False)
```

Error Message:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the benefits of dictionaries by looping over all the keys in the `dnew` dictionary for each element in the `data['features']` list.

E.Coms noted the problem you're having but that only checks the first item in the list, (`data["features"][0]`)

Perhaps the following will solve your problem.

```
for key in data["features"]:
    citykey = (key["properties"]["City"])
    ratingvalue = (key["properties"]["Rating"])
    #print(citykey + "| " + ratingvalue)

    if citykey in dnew:
        key["properties"]["Rating"] = dnew[citykey]
```

Answer (score 1):

It misses a number index after "features" as it's a list not a dictionary.

`data["features"][0]["properties"]["Rating"]`